# Shared Powerpoint file with an automatic VBA saving

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to make a Powerpoint quiz for a company that will share it on its network drive where everybody should have access to.

The idea is every employee could participate in quiz and after answering all the questions, the score is saved to the last slide and all the scores are listed for the current employee.

I already know how to make the quiz part of that but I have not found a single tutorial *how to do the saving thing –– add score to the last slide's list and save the file.*

Is this doable? Can the file in the network drive be updated, saved with VBA, so that whoever opens the file next, will see all the scores on the last slide?

I was first thinking of auto emailing the result but then figured it out that it's not possible.

Does it matter if there's Windows and Mac users (don't know if there are any mac users)?

thanks in advance

Comment: Seems easier to auto-email the results...

Comment: @DavidZemens How can I auto-email those results so that user could not alter the text that is being sent?

Comment: I'm gonna need more information... you should probably start a new question: "How to send an email from PPT using VBA" or something like that. Make sure to include examples/screenshots of the data that you want to send, and describe where it is located in the Presentation (e.g., in a textbox, in a slide's content placeholder, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

First off, you'll need to make sure that only one user opens the presentation at a time.  Or work out a way to distribute copies of the presentation to each user and have each copy write the scores to a common file on the network.

> > I have not found a single tutorial how to do the saving thing –– add score to the last slide's list and save the file.

To save the file, invoke the Presentation's .Save method

```
ActivePresentation.Save
```

To add a text box and text to the last slide in the presentation, something like this:

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape

Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 500, 200)
With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = "YOUR SCORE HERE"
End With
```

Or if you've already added the shape and want to change the text:

```
Dim oSh As Shape

With ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
    Set oSh = .Shapes("ShapeName")  ' substitute the actual shape name
    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "YOUR SCORE HERE"
    End With
End With    ' Last Slide
```